# Dynamic belongsTo with same targetKey with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to create a file table that should be able to have relation to several other tables. A file could be connected to a "client", "user", "document", and so on.
I know that I could create one relation table for each of these and connect a client and a file for example. But since there can be up to 10 different ways to connect a file, I'm thinking about having only one relational table that would have these columns:

```
file_id
resource_type
resource_id
```

So a file could be related to a "Client" and the relational row would look like this:
file_id: 123
resource_type: 'client'
resource_id: '444'

Is there a way to achieve this in Sequelize?
Pseudo code example:

```
File.belongsTo(models.Client, {
  foreignKey: 'client_id',
  targetKey: 'resource_id',
  where: { resource_type: 'client' } // I know this is not a thing
});

File.belongsTo(models.Document, {
  foreignKey: 'document_id',
  targetKey: 'resource_id',
  where: { resource_type: 'document' }
});
```

If there are other better ways to structure this, I'm happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to look at [Polymorphic associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/polymorphic-associations.html). It seems this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I wanted. It was way too long since I came  across this type of relation in SQL. It's hard to search for help sometimes when you don't know the exact term for it. Thanks